# UICollectionview Custom layout with Dynamic data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom CollectionViewFlowLayout with thousands of dynamic paginated data coming through REST API.

I have implemented [Raywenderlich's Pinterest like layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest). Which is okay if you know the cell height already. but the problem is, In my data Image size and text sizes are totally dynamic.

I am trying to calculate the cell height via delegate method but it is not working as I expected.

Also What is the best perfomant way to re-calculate cell attributes for the new ui CollectionView Cells?

[image]

Comment: I believe the backend is able to provide image proportions. So, images should not be an issue. Text size might be calculated on the background when received from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your cell subclass and override `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_:)` like this:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

                // Ensures that cell expands horizontally while adjusting itself vertically.
                let preferredSize = systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel)

                layoutAttributes.size = preferredSize
                return layoutAttributes
    }
```